# How to continuous animation in Tweenmax ?

Tags: jquery, gsap

I am trying to animate continuous animate one image left to right and i want it to repeat no.of times(left to right only).i have written like this.

```
  <script>
   TweenMax.to(".image",40,{
    left:'960px',
    onComplete:function(){
        $(".image").css({"left":"-50px"});
        TweenMax.to(".image",40,{
            repeat:-1,
        })
      }
   })
  </script>
  <div class="image"></div>
```

Comment: You need to read the rather extensive documentation. Greensock has staggering built in, you can do both animations with staggering, you don't need to use the callback, and the `repeat` goes on the outer most animation, not on the inner animation, otherwise it's correct, setting it to `-1` makes it recursive indefinitively.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple function definition to do this;

```
 <script>
   function animateImage() {
       $(".image").css({"left":"-50px"});
       TweenMax.to(".image",40,{
           left: '960px',
           onComplete: animateImage
       });
   }
  </script>
  <div class="image"></div>
```

Comment: Tahir's solution is cleaner, and more correct / primitive to TweenMax.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this would help:

```
TweenMax.fromTo($(".image"), 40, {left: -50}, {left: 960, repeat: -1});
```